# Show text on a Dialog Box

Tags: c++, windows, atl

I am creating an ATL project and I want to present some text results through a Dialog Box. I have all the text results in a list< CString >.

I am not deeply acquainted with ATL/MFC matters so I need a suggestion on how I can accomplish the functionality of the project. I decided to make use of an edit control on the Dialog Box to contain and present finally the text lines. My concern is how I can convey the CString on the edit control. Obviously I need some kind of a function by the Edit Control / Dialog Box. The Dialog Box comes with a class CTestDlg. Where and how should I add the code which is responsible for the Cstring elements to appear on the Dialog Box?

The class CTestDlg contains particularly the method:

```
LRESULT CTestDlg::OnEnChangeEdit1(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
{
// TODO: 

return 0;
```

}

in which the function to add the text is to be set. I am still though anware of the way it can be done since the function setWindowText can not be recognised inside that class. Lacks the class an include?

Comment: Do you think a multiline edit control would be good for you? That is, you will need to `SetWindowText` with a joined string, with lines separated with `\r\n`, and then `GetWindowText` this back and parse out the lines.